# tikz legend with only 1 bar, not 2

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have bar graphs made with tikz picture and pgfplots and the legend has two bars shown for each item. If this were printed in black and white I can see it being confusing given that I have multiple bars per tick. Is it possible to globally change the legend picture to have only 1 bar?

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{figure}[tbp]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.26\linewidth}
\caption{Average Playback Version}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
%x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
xlabel=Available Bandwidth (Mbps),
ylabel=APV,
xtick={0, 1},
xticklabels={Early, Late},
enlarge x limits=0.35,
x=2.5cm,
enlarge y limits=upper,
legend style={at={(0.5,1.0)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar,
bar width=5pt,
ymin=0,
]
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,2.036363636363636) (1,4.803030303030303)}; %none
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,2.171875) (1,4.98)}; %1 ahead
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,2.765625) (1,5.520618556701031)}; %2 ahead
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,3.5084745762711864) (1,5.904255319148936)}; %3 ahead
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,3.3225806451612905) (1,5.938388625592417)}; %4 ahead
\legend{0,1,2,3,4}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.26\linewidth}
\caption{Playback Smoothness}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
%x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
xlabel=Available Bandwidth (Mbps),
ylabel=PS,
xtick={0, 1},
xticklabels={Early, Late},
enlarge x limits=0.35,
x=2.5cm,
ymax=1,
enlarge y limits=upper,
legend style={at={(0.5,1.0)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar,
bar width=5pt,
ymin=0,
]
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,0.24098054972207325) (1,0.24153409339341353)}; %none
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,0.114057913312868) (1,0.2756032344823675)}; %1 ahead
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,0.051916399143237965) (1,0.18031661670978735)}; %2 ahead
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,0.06390840028231044) (1,0.36195905410949436)}; %3 ahead
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,0.04319574602657975) (1,0.48586289928460025)}; %4 ahead
\legend{0,1,2,3,4}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.26\linewidth}
\caption{Prefetching Overhead}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
%x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
xlabel=Available Bandwidth (Mbps),
ylabel=PO,
xtick={0, 1},
xticklabels={Early, Late},
enlarge x limits=0.35,
x=2.5cm,
ymax=1,
enlarge y limits=upper,
legend style={at={(0.5,1.0)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar,
bar width=5pt,
ymin=0,
]
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,0) (1,0)}; %none
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,0.20614441700821615) (1,0.011143061898431643)}; %1 ahead
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,0.7352518529340072) (1,0.08344647990992549)}; %2 ahead
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,0.9219019138395939) (1,0.07364705301195329)}; %3 ahead
\addplot
    coordinates{(0,1.4445764512661277) (1,0.027578648257207166)}; %4 ahead
\legend{0,1,2,3,4}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{PC Browser: Long-Term Decreases 4 Mbps - 0.5 Mbps}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `\pgfplotsset{
 ybar/.append style={
  area legend
 }
}`